# Why they have different MSVC compiler when using different python version to build package with Cython?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, python-3.7, setuptools

I try to build the wheel package with Cython in my project.

My command:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

It could build success with Python3.6, but fail with Python3.7 and Python3.8.

They have the same os environment variables and they have installed the same package dependency.

By comparing two kinds of output, I found that they use different msvc compiler.

Python3.6 works with msvc2019, the full compile command of Cython:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -IC:\Python36_64\include -IC:\Python36_64\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcbuild\myproject/myservice_obj.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\build\myproject/myservice_obj.obj
```

Python3.7 and Python3.8 work with msvc2014, the full compile command of Cython:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Python37_64\include -IC:\Python37_64\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" /Tcbuild\myproject/myservice_obj.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\build\myproject/myservice_obj.obj
```

**Questions:**

Why they have different setting of building process?

How to use msvc2019 to build package with python3.7?

Comment: My wild guess is that you may have a more recent version of `setuptools` installed for Python 3.6 than for 3.7/3.8. Run `py -3.6 -c "import setuptools; print(setuptools.__version__)"` and compare the output with what you get when running the same command, but with `-3.7` and `-3.8`.

Comment: @hoefling Thanks for your answer. I have tried it in my virtualenv. The output both are 42.0.2.

Comment: Another wild guess is that your Python distributions were built with different compilers from the start. When your run `py -3.X -c "from distutils.msvc9compiler import get_build_version as v; print(v())"`, do you get 14.1 for all three Python versions?

Comment: Yes, they are all `14.1`.